# Planning site URL in Prod

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a Production SharePoint 2010 setup on the server with a default site collection that runs on port 80. I need to migrate a new site collection from Test to Prod. I want the new and existing site collections to co-exists on Production.

In Test,

The default site collection URL is as, /servername/

New SiteCollection has a URL as servername/sites/newSiteCollName/

In Prod,

The default site collection URL is as, /servername/

I need to get rid of /servername/site/newSiteCollName/ from the URL in Prod. Instead it should be some friendly name for Public access such as

www.NewSiteCollectionName.com/

Can I have a new Host Header site collection in the same web application on which we currently we have default path based site collection in Prod. Also the existing path based site collection has Alternate Access mapping Enabled in prod.

In default zones, it has /servername/

In Intranet zone, it has /sharePoint (SharePoint is the DNS record)

How do I achieve it?

Cheers,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're migrating the site collection from test to prod if you're doing an export / import operation you could potentially just restore to the URL you've stated above.. if you're doing this via a content database move then perhaps a managed path could be the answer. I might not be reading the question correctly however.

Good post on managed paths
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/zach/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I need to know the URL naming strategy and currently evaluating path based or Host head based site collection.